# Laravel: Show output of a console command inside a migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I created a command to do some data manipulation on a very large database table and as it takes fair enough time to complete, i took the benefits of progress bar plus echoing some information on the console.

to automate stuff and reduce human errors, i want to call my command inside a laravel migration using [programmatically-executing-commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands) style and it works but the problem is it wont print any output from corresponding command inside the console

i think i should pass the current Output-buffer that `artisan:migrate` is using to the `Artisan::call` function to make it work but had no luck to access it inside the migration

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on [@ettdro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203513/2795904), the `Artisan::call` method has the following signature:

```php
Artisan::call(string $command, array $parameters = [], $outputBuffer = null);
```

As you can see, the method accepts an output buffer as its 3rd argument. You can pass that output buffer to the method and the command logs will show up on the console.

Here's an example:

```php
<?php

use App\Console\Commands\YourConsoleCommand;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;


class SomeDbMigration extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $output = new ConsoleOutput();
        Artisan::call(YourConsoleCommand::class, ['--some-option' => true], $output);
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $output = new ConsoleOutput();
        Artisan::call(YourConsoleCommand::class, ['--some-option' => false], $output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ConsoleOutput` provided by Symfony to print out in the console after calling Artisan command. Make sure to use it in your desired .php file like so `use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;`.

You could have something like this:

```
$output = new ConsoleOutput();
$exitCode = Artisan::call('your call');
if ($exitCode == -1)
    $output->writeln("<bg=red;options=bold>Error occured while migration rollback " . "Exit code: " . $exitCode ."</>");
else {
    $output->writeln("<bg=blue;options=bold>Rollbacked successfully! Exit code: " . $exitCode ."</>");
}
```

See in my example you can also add colors to your text, that could be useful to have better visuals on errors and success, see more at this link: https://symfony.com/search?q=ConsoleOutput